# How do I ensure Breeze.js save doesn't trigger the browser's authentication dialogue?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web, breeze

I'm using Breeze in a single page application saving to an asp.net web api server. My app is using forms authentication and my Breeze controller is decorated with the Authorize attribute;

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize]
[BreezeController]
public class ReminderController : ApiController
{ ... }
```

I'm seeing an issue where as soon as Breeze attempts to save, and *before* the request completes, the browser instantly pops up a username/password authentication dialog. I'm not entirely sure why this happens as the aspx cookie is not set to expire but I can replicate it by logging in to my app, deleting the cookie and then triggering a Breeze save. If I click cancel on the dialog, my server responds with a 401 which my client code handles. I want to ensure the auth dialog is never shown to the user. This happens in Chrome and IE currently but I'm sure it didn't do this in older releases of Chrome stable.

The request can be seen here, still listed as Pending while the dialog is displayed

[image: Request]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the custom Authorize attribute I am using to get around this issue in our application (warning, auto converted from VB.NET to C#, so it may not be 100% correct!).  It sends a 403 status instead of a 401 if the user is already authenticated, to stop the browser from prompting the user to log on.  Tested in IE and Firefox.

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom <see cref="AuthorizeAttribute"/> for WebAPI that sends a 403 Forbidden status instead
/// of 401 Unauthorized, if the user is authenticated, so that the browser will not display a
/// logon prompt.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            // If the user is authenticated then we don't want to prompt them to authenticate.
            // Ajax requests get a forbidden status code to stop the browser login prompt,
            // since Unauthorized (401) would cause the browser to display a login dialog.
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden");
        } else {
            // If the user isn't authenticated then do the normal thing
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as I can't seem to find a way to remove the `WWW-Authenticate` headers from the 401 response (maybe IIS is adding them?) A 403 is seemingly the only way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no reliable, cross browser way to prevent the dialogue at the client end. Checking Fiddler I can see the actual response to the ajax request when the cookie has expired (it's annoying Chrome dev tools don't show this and just sits at 'Pending') contains `WWW-Authenticate` headers. Strangely, IIS Express running locally *doesn't* include these headers and the dialogue never shows. It's only apparent when I publish to full IIS on my provider. The plan is to override the Web Api Authorize attribute (the method which handles authorise failure) and remove the `WWW-Authenticate` headers.

I have no idea why IIS 8.0/Express return different headers.